# How send a push notification without installation?

Tags: notifications, push-notification, parse-platform, push

My question is as follows:

I have a database on another server with the appropriate records of the devices.

I can send a notification by REST API without necessarily making an installation registry?

Something like: 
"Send notification to the following devices: 
- id1 
- id2 
- Id3 "

My idea is to continue to use my other server without getting spending requests or hosting Parse. Only use the push notifications service.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what types of devices you are referring to (iOS? Android? Windows Phone?), but push notifications to mobile devices always require an application to be installed on the target device, since the notification is sent to a specific application on a specific device.

And the only way you can get a device ID (which you can use to send push notification to a device) is by having an application on the device send that ID to your server after obtaining it from the relevant push notifications service (APNS for iOS, GCM for Android, etc...).

Comment: Yes, I have an app with Parse, but i dont want to use others Parse's services.
I just want to send devicesIds to Parse and then Parse send push notifications to them.